# How to pre-fill a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

Like :

```
class Article (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name="articles")

    def __init___(self):
        self.user = 'Friendy'
```

Comment: Do you mean default values for all objects of `Article` or just values for an instance of `Article`?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean to add a default value to the `user` field, there are two ways: either a simple value based default, or you can use a callable as the default.  The documentation for this can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default

If you want to default to specific user, then you would need to know the `id` of the user, like so:

```
class Article (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'User', 
        related_name="articles", 
        default=1, 
        help_text="There better be a user with an id of 1 or this will not work",
    )

    def __init___(self):
        self.user = 'Friendy'
```

The other way is to define a callable that returns the id of the user, like so:

```
def get_first_user():
    user = User.objects.first()
    if user:
        return user.pk
    return None

class Article (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'User', 
        related_name="articles", 
        default=get_first_user, 
        help_text="There better be a user with an id of 1 or this will not work",
    )

    def __init___(self):
        self.user = 'Friendy'
```

The reason we return the id and not the User instance is because of this line in the docs:

> For fields like ForeignKey that map to model instances, defaults should be the value of the field they reference (pk unless to_field is set) instead of model instances.